# Can I share online some complaints I have raised against my university?

Tags: defamation

Recently, I sent a complaint to my university for a problem I had.
I got a reply.

Can I share the official documents online? Or am I liable of defamation?

Best
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I share online some complaints I have raised against my university?
>
> Or am I liable of defamation?

Yes, you may divulge the official documents unless they contain "sealed records", special information that would be protected from disclosure, or if prohibited (in part or in its entirety) by the court through an order.

Merely posting court documents does not make you liable for defamation. Where you would need to be very careful, though, is on not making any statements which the university or alluded persons can reasonably allege that constitute *false and defamatory statements of fact*.

Additionally, statements which the publisher frames as "opinion" (with language such as "*I think*" or "*in my opinion*") but which essentially convey or insinuate facts are treated by the courts (at least in theory) as *statements of fact*.

Comment: And the question of copyright in the university's letter?

Comment: @DaleM The university is extremely unlikely to prevail in a copyright suit about its litigation documents. An accused party usually wants the public to know his/its side of the story, whence suing for copyright of its defenses would be frivolous at best. By publishing, the OP would actually forestall a holding of the type of [*Huckabee v. Time Warner*, 19 S.W.3d 413, 425 (2000)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/200043219sw3d4131423): "*A broadcaster's omission of facts may be actionable if it so distorts the viewers' perception that they receive a substantially false impression of the event*".